# median filter in Opencl

Tags: filter, kernel, opencl

I'm new with the Opencl Program and I write a Kernel code of one median filter 3*3 it compile but it doesn't load in the cpu I always have 0 as value and I don't know the reason.this is my code

```
uiRGBA[0] = pSrc[iPrev + x - 1];
uiRGBA[1] = pSrc[iPrev + x];
uiRGBA[2] = pSrc[iPrev + x + 1];

uiRGBA[3] = pSrc[iOffset + x - 1];
uiRGBA[4] = pSrc[iOffset + x];
uiRGBA[5] = pSrc[iOffset + x + 1];

uiRGBA[6] = pSrc[iNext + x - 1];
uiRGBA[7] = pSrc[iNext + x];
uiRGBA[8] = pSrc[iNext + x + 1];

uint uiResult = 0;
uint uiMask = 0xFF;

for(int ch = 0; ch < 3; ch++)
{

    // extract next color channel
    uint r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8;
    r0=uiRGBA[0]& uiMask;
    r1=uiRGBA[1]& uiMask;
    r2=uiRGBA[2]& uiMask;
    r3=uiRGBA[3]& uiMask;
    r4=uiRGBA[4]& uiMask;
    r5=uiRGBA[5]& uiMask;
    r6=uiRGBA[6]& uiMask;
    r7=uiRGBA[7]& uiMask;
    r8=uiRGBA[8]& uiMask;
    //*ipSource, *ipDest


    //neue Version des Filters 
    for(row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            count++;
            for(int i = max(0, row - radius); i < min(row + radius, height-1); i++)
            {
                for(int j = max(0, col-radius); j < min(col + radius , width-1); j++)
                {
                    if((value = pSrc[j + i * width] ) != 0)
                    {
                        dMedianfield[++count] = value;

                    }
                }

            }
            if(count)
            {
                pDst[row + col] = dMedianfield[++count];
            }
        }

    }

}

pDst[col + row] = 8;
return;
```

}
with the last line I try to load the value 8 in the cpu but I have a 0 instead.

Comment: Are you checking errors on all of the host side api calls? If not you should.

Comment: yes I did it but I will do it again

Comment: You're not showing your host code (or even the whole kernel) so it's difficult to say. I suspect you're not transferring the buffer back correctly, since you're writing `8` but not getting that back. Debug the memory transfer first before working on the median algorithm.

Comment: I'm finally found the solution . the problem came from the fact that the first code was burn in the cache memory that while even if I changed the code the compiler recognized only the old version to resolve it I have added the following line at the beginning of the main function                                                                                                          _putenv_s("CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE", "1");